# Is LWP::UserAgent not thread-safe?

Tags: perl, multithreading, thread-safety, lwp-useragent

I'm running 40-or-so threads with the following subroutine:

```
my $app = shift;
my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new();
$ua->timeout(5);
my $response = $ua->get($$app{'watch_url'});
my $new_md5;
if ($response->is_success()) {
    $new_md5 = md5_hex($response->content());
}
return ($$app{'short_name'}, $$app{'watch_md5'}, $new_md5);
```

Core dumps ensue about 3/4 of the time. LWP and LWP::UserAgent are pure Perl, so I'm caught off-guard by this. Is LWP::UserAgent not thread-safe?

**Update:**

Here's a minimal version to reproduce the issue:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use threads;
use LWP::UserAgent;

sub check_app {
    my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new();
    $ua->timeout(5);
    $ua->get('http://www.flatdoc.com/?' . rand(10));
}

my @threads;
for (my $i = 0; $i < 40; $i++) {
    my $thread = threads->create(\&check_app);
    push(@threads, $thread);
}
foreach (@threads) {
    $_->join();
}
```

Comment: I would check Digest::MD5. Every time I use it I end up wrapping it in an eval.

Comment: I did test the script without it and ended up with core dumps at the same rate.

Comment: You aren't using Thread::Pool for your threads are you?  There seems to be some agreement that that module can cause problems.

Comment: Strip out as much as possible from a complete test program and still have the problem, and show it to us?

Comment: Unless you show a full example including how you use threads, nobody will be able to help you.

Comment: Alright, here's some more code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Non-thread safe pure-Perl code does not cause a segfault (in fact, no pure Perl code should cause a segfault).  A bug in Perl causes a segfault.  And threads in Perl are historically very buggy, but they've gotten a lot better.

Your code runs fine in 5.10.1, and HTTP::Lite probably just doesn't tickle whatever perl bug you've run into.  Likely you just need to use a newer version of Perl.  The older and closer to Redhat you get, the less stable threads are.  If you're going to use threads, use the newest Perl you can get your hands on.

As an alternative to threads, you can use something like [Parallel::ForkManager](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Parallel-ForkManager), [LWP::Parallel](http://search.cpan.org/dist/ParallelUserAgent/) or even the amazing [forks](http://search.cpan.org/dist/forks) module which emulates threads using fork.

Comment: What about Redhat makes threads buggy? It's true that I am working on CentOS boxes.

Comment: They're notorious for patching Perl, throwing experimental patches into stable versions, messing things up and then not releasing a fix.  It got particularly bad in the early 5.8's when they broke Unicode fairly hard and then set the default to UTF-8.  Things may have improved, I remain wary of any Perl rpm.