# Perl parallel crawler multithreading

Tags: multithreading, perl

I have a multi threaded Perl crawler which is working fine if I declare  URLs in array.How ever if I read the URLs from DB I am getting "segmentation failure" error.Please help me to fix this issue.Thanks

Direct URL declaration

```
use 5.012; use warnings;
use threads;
use Thread::Queue;
use LWP::UserAgent;

use constant THREADS => 10;

my $queue = Thread::Queue->new();
my @URLs =qw(http://www.example.com
http://www.example.com1
http://www.example.com2 );

print @URLs;
my @threads;

for (1..THREADS) {
    push @threads, threads->create(sub {
        my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
        $ua->timeout(5); # short timeout for easy testing.
        while(my $task = $queue->dequeue) {
            my $response = eval{ $ua->get($task)->status_line };
            say "$task --> $response";
        }
    });
}

$queue->enqueue(@URLs);
$queue->enqueue(undef) for 1..THREADS;
# ... here work is done
$_->join foreach @threads;
```

Trying to read the URLs from DB

```
my $dbh = DBI->connect("DBI:mysql:$database;host=$server", $username, $password) # Get the rows from database
    || die "Could not connect to database: $DBI::errstr";

my $sth = $dbh->prepare('select cname,url,xpath,region from competitors')    #query to select required fields
    || die "$DBI::errstr";

$sth->execute();

if ($sth->rows < 0) {
    print "Sorry, no domains found.\n";
}
else {                                                
    while (my $results = $sth->fetchrow_hashref) {
        my $competitor= $results->{cname};                      
        my $url = $results->{url};                         
        my $xpath = $results->{xpath};
        my $region = $results->{region};

        push(my @all,$url);   

        use constant THREADS => 10;
        my $queue = Thread::Queue->new();
        my @URLs=@all;
        my @threads;

        for (1..THREADS) {
            push @threads, threads->create(sub {
                my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
                $ua->timeout(500); # short timeout for easy testing.
                while(my $task = $queue->dequeue) {
                    my $response = eval{ $ua->get($task)->status_line };
                    print  "$task --> $response";
                }
            });
        }

        $queue->enqueue( @URLs);
        $queue->enqueue(undef) for 1..THREADS;
        # ... here work is done
        $_->join foreach @threads;
    }

}  #close db

$sth->finish;
$dbh->disconnect;
```

Expected o/p

```
www.example.com-->200 ok

www.example.com1-->200 ok
```

Current o/p

Segmentation error

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1843932/is-lwpuseragent-not-thread-safe

Comment: What version of perl and libraries are you on?

Comment: btw, LWP::UserAgent timeouts are in seconds, so a 500 timeout is a long time out, not a short one.

Comment: @ikegami: Hi i modified that timeout from 5 to 500 for testing purpose but forget to remove those comments.Thanks for pointing that one

Answer (score 2):

Your `$sth` and `$dbh` are still around when you create the thread, creating a copy of them, which is a [no-no](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DBI#Threads_and_Thread_Safety).

> newly created threads must make their own connections to the database. Handles can't be shared across threads.

Better scoping of your variables should avoid the problem.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use threads;
use Thread::Queue 3.01 qw( );

use constant NUM_WORKERS => 10;

sub worker {
   my ($ua, $url) = @_;
   ...
}

{
   my $q = Thread::Queue->new();

   for (1..NUM_WORKERS) {
      async {
         my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new();
         while ( my $url = $q->dequeue() ) {
            eval { worker($ua, $url); 1 }
               or warn $@;
         }
      };
   }

   {
      my $dbh = DBI->connect(..., { RaiseError => 1 });
      my $sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT ...');
      $sth->execute();
      while ( my $row = $sth->fetchrow_hashref() ) {
         $q->enqueue($row->{url});
      }
   }

   $q->end();
   $_->join for threads->list;
}
```

Comment: Here's the citation in the docs: "Because of this (possibly temporary) restriction, newly created threads must make their own connections to the database. Handles can't be shared across threads. But BEWARE, some underlying database APIs (the code the DBD driver uses to talk to the database, often supplied by the database vendor) are not thread safe." https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#Threads-and-Thread-Safety  The situation has gotten much better since this was written, but you still can't share a DBI handle across threads.

Answer (score 0):

You should declare @all outside of the while loop, then, when the URLs are pushed, close that loop and go on

```
my $dbh = DBI->connect("DBI:mysql:$database;host=$server", $username, $password) # Get the rows from database
    || die "Could not connect to database: $DBI::errstr";

my $sth = $dbh->prepare('select cname,url,xpath,region from competitors')    #query to select required fields
    || die "$DBI::errstr";

$sth->execute();

# >> declare your URL-array before starting to fetch
my @URLs;
if ($sth->rows < 0) {
    print "Sorry, no domains found.\n";
}

else {


    while (my $results = $sth->fetchrow_hashref) {
        my $competitor= $results->{cname};                      
        my $url = $results->{url};                         
        my $xpath = $results->{xpath};
        my $region = $results->{region};

        push(@URLs,$url);   
    }

}  

$sth->finish;
$dbh->disconnect;

use constant THREADS => 10;
my $queue = Thread::Queue->new();
my @threads;

for (1..THREADS) {
        push @threads, threads->create(sub {
        my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
        $ua->timeout(500); # short timeout for easy testing.
        while(my $task = $queue->dequeue) {
            my $response = eval{ $ua->get($task)->status_line };
            print  "$task --> $response";
        }
    });
}

$queue->enqueue( @URLs);
$queue->enqueue(undef) for 1..THREADS;
# ... here work is done
$_->join foreach @threads;
```

Comment: Explaining why would make this a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

Segfaults are very rare as a result of perl code. They're memory related, and *usually* mean a problem in external binaries. (I'd be betting on DBI here)

Threads in particular have a lot of legacy issues - they're getting better in newer versions of perl though. I would *strongly* recommend that you consider upgrading to a recent version of perl if you haven't already. I know that isn't always an option, but it's a good idea.

It's really hard to second guess your problem, as I don't have your DB, so I can't recreate it.

I would suggest that generally there's a few things you can do to keep threads 'clean' - the way your code works, is the DB handles are in scope within the threads. I would avoid doing that. Declare the thread sub right at the top, with as narrow a scope as possible.

I will note though:

```
push ( my @all, $url );
```

probably doesn't do what you think it does!

But yes, taking your code I'd put it like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use threads;
use Thread::Queue;
use LWP;

my $num_threads = 10;

my $work_q = Thread::Queue->new();

sub worker {
    my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
    $ua->timeout(500);    # short timeout for easy testing.
    while ( my $task = $work_q->dequeue ) {
        my $response = eval { $ua->get($task)->status_line };
        print "$task --> $response";
    }
}


## fetch_list

sub fetch_url_list {
    my $dbh = DBI->connect( "DBI:mysql:$database;host=$server",
        $username, $password )    # Get the rows from database
        || die "Could not connect to database: $DBI::errstr";

    my $sth =
        $dbh->prepare( 'select cname,url,xpath,region from competitors'
        )                         #query to select required fields
        || die "$DBI::errstr";

    $sth->execute();


    if ( $sth->rows < 0 ) {
        print "Sorry, no domains found.\n";
    }
    else {
        while ( my $results = $sth->fetchrow_hashref ) {
            my $competitor = $results->{cname};
            my $url        = $results->{url};
            my $xpath      = $results->{xpath};
            my $region     = $results->{region};

            $work_q -> enqueue ( $url );
        }
    }
    $sth->finish;
    $dbh->disconnect;
}

for ( 1 .. $num_threads ) {
    threads->create( \&worker );
}

fetch_url_list();
$work_q->end;

foreach my $thr ( threads->list() ) {
    $thr->join();
}
```

This way - none of your threads have the DB stuff 'in scope', and the DB doesn't have thread stuff in scope. That reduces odds of 'pollution' causing you problems. In particular - threads when they start 'copy' everything in the current scope, which can do really wierd things when they're objects. (e.g. such as the DB handles)

Failing that, I would consider looking at a 'forking' approach. Threads are good at passing data back and forth, but forks are generally more efficient (definitely on Unix based systems) when you don't need to pass data back and forth (and you don't, you're just running a test and printing a result).